# How to shorten code on nodejs, puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Sorry for my English I use node.js, puppeteer. There is such a code

```
let clicked_editorial_button = await page.evaluate(() => {
    if(document.querySelector("button.section-editorial-button") !== null)
    {
      document.querySelector('button.section-editorial-button').click();
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Can all this be done through a function or through a method? Ideally, you could write like this:

```
let clicked_editorial_button = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.click_or_return_false("button.section-editorial-button");
  });
```

Is there any way to set *click_or_return_false* for *document* to work in any *await page.evaluate*? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add functions in `evaluate()` context, use this :

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(fs.readFileSync('./helperFunctions.js', 'utf8'));
```

With your functions in `./helperFunctions.js` (you need to code the function properly):

```
window.clicked_editorial_button = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.click_or_return_false("button.section-editorial-button");
});
```

Then, you can call `clicked_editorial_button()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to run the function on every `page.evaluate`, you can define the function first in a `page.evaluate` method.

NOTE: This function only worked perfectly if the page isn't refreshed or navigated to another URL.

```
await page.evaluate ( () => {
    var clicked_or_false = function (selector) {
        if( document.querySelector( selector ) !== null ) {
            document.querySelector( selector ).click()
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
})
```

Then, you can call this function on every `page.evaluate`

```
await page.evaluate ( () => {

    if (clicked_or_false) {
        clicked_or_false ('#someid')
        clicked_or_false ('.anyclass')
        clicked_or_false ('input[type="submit"]')
    }

})
```